# What exactly does "auto" mean for the CSS top property?

Tags: css

I saw in css-tricks.com a css technique to make a sidebar sticky, which used the "position" property and the "auto" value for the top property. It says:

> The easiest way to handle this is just to use CSS fixed positioning.
>   Our sidebar is within a #page-wrap div with relative positioning, so
>   the sidebar will set inside there, then we just push it over into
>   place with margin.

**Preview:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   html {
    background: #f5f5f5;
   }
   
   body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   
   #page-wrap { 
     position: relative; 
     margin: 0 auto; 
     width: 600px; 
     height: 3000px;
     background: #ccc;
   }

   #sidebar { 
     position: fixed; 
     top: auto;
     margin-top: 50px;
     margin-left: 410px; 
     width: 190px; 
     height: 400px;
     background: blue;
   }
  </style>
 <body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
   <div id="sidebar">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It worked. But now I am confused about the way the "auto" value works. w3schools defines the "auto" value for the top property as follow:

> Lets the browser calculate the top edge position. This is default.

So that means if the auto value is used, the top edge of the parent container is actually the edge of the browser, not the one of the container?

Comment: w3schools is not a trustworthy source for information and should not be cited as a reference.

Comment: @zzzzBov What's wrong with w3schools? Is it really not trustworthy?

Comment: @rp.beltran, historically it was so bad that [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) was created. The information often was (and in some cases still is) dangerously incorrect by *appearing* to be true, and by *appearing* to be affiliated with the w3c, while actually being neither. A good source of information would be the actual w3c specs, or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) which uses a wiki format so that errors can be corrected as soon as they are identified.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip there. That is quite interesting.